# Android System Color Constants

Tags: android, styles

Android programming is driving me crazy.  The XML or programmable ways for GUI development is making a right old dogs breakfast of the code--some stuff here, some stuff there.

My current frustration is trying to keep it all XML and I would like to set the background color of the `TextView` the same color as the background color of a `Button` without having to specify the exact color code.  I would like to use a system constant, something like `java.awt.SystemColor.control`, but specified in XML.

Is there anyway of doing this without having to respecify a bunch of stuff?  I'm looking for a solution like: `android:background="{Insert constant here}"`.

Answer (score 39):

You should have a file in res/values called colors.xml, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="grey">#7A7A7A</color>
    <color name="background">#0044AA</color>
    <color name="bluelight">#449DEF</color>
    <color name="bluedark">#2F6699</color>
    <color name="greenlight">#70C656</color>
    <color name="greendark">#53933F</color>
    <color name="orangelight">#F3AE1B</color>
    <color name="orangedark">#BB6008</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can just call the color in xml like this:

```
android:background="@color/greenlight"
```

Comment: But I do not want to specify the color.  I want to specify a system style.

Comment: This is generally the preferred way to do it, as there aren't many system defined colours, however you can use android:background="@android:color/white". You can find a full list here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

Comment: I have a color constant for ex : 17170449 which I need to convert into the hexa decimal code. is it possible? Thanks in advance @MattHarris

Answer (score 27):

You can use things like "@color/white", or for android system constants, "@android:color/holo_red_light". Alternatively if you want more control, you can always define a common background in a drawable and set the background to "@drawable/mydrawable"

List of resources available for android:color here (like background_dark): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

Comment: This is the problem that I am having with Android.  I do not want to have to redefine everything myself.  I want to use standards on the system.  I don't care what those standards are I just want a similar user look and feel.

Comment: That's precisely why you should use android:color/ ... there's lots of existing presets that aren't color specific and will change based on the manufacturer. updated answer with link

Comment: Just a heads up, your example is incorrect, there is no "@android:color/red"

Comment: And correct you are @RedLenses ... updated the answer to be one of the valid values from the documentation :)

Comment: Hi @JoelMartinez can you please show example of using a small image as a repeat in the background. I did it like this - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/be2857ca33e83498ab34b78c13a48ca1 - it doesnt work right for me.

Answer (score 3):

check out this page: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-color-in-android.html

You can use: "@android:color/white" in your xml. I imagine that a few other common colors are supported, but I don't know for sure which ones.

The preferred solution is generally to create your own colors.xml resource file and reference the ones that you put inside there.

Answer (score 1):

used like this  : `android:background="#FF00FF"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need using xml file to create a constants' XML,

it can help you:
[Java constants file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866190/java-constants-file)

Comment: I want to do it in XML not Java.  I can get the colors via Java programming but the intention is to the use XML for the GUI design and have that all in one location.  I don't want half my GUI in XML and half in Java.