# How to Change the Android Notification Icon/Status Bar Icon for Push-notification in #flutter?

Tags: push-notification, flutter

I want to replace the default Icon with my own icon for Push-notifications.

Now the App show the Icon as White box .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just add a meta-data inside  tag in your manifest file.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->


<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="When Coin"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

***NOTE: Before starting, make sure your icon/image has a transparent background. The solution will seem like it's not working if your image background has a color.***

Want to generate mipmap icons, try [appicon.co/](https://appicon.co/)

Comment: You also need to generate the file in case anyone was wondering if this was some special Android setting..

Answer (score 80):

Ajay's answer is correct, but to expand on it a bit:

***NOTE: Before starting, make sure your icon/image has a transparent background. The solution will seem like it's not working if your image background has a color.***

1. Create your mipmap notification icon. You can do this easily using [Roman's Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) - Click on "Notification Icon Generator"
2. On the left panel, click "Image" to upload your own image or use ClipArt or text as provided.
3. After you're done, click the download button in the upper-right to download the zip file. Alternative to Roman's Notification Icon Generator, try [appicon.co](https://appicon.co/)
4. In the zip file, your icon files will be in individual directories with the same name as your mipmap directories in your project directory (e.g., "mipmap-hdpi", "mipmap-mdpi", etc.). Move the icon files to their respective folders within your project.
5. In your AndroidManifest.xml file (located at `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`), add the meta-data **within the "application" tag**:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package">

    <application
        android:name="com.your.package.Application"
        android:label="YourAppName"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
          android:resource="@mipmap/your_icon_file_name" />
```

6. Save your file. You may need to stop and restart or uninstall and reinstall your app for the notification icon to start showing.
7. Your icon is probably white, so if you want to change the color you can add the following meta-data tag below the icon meta-data tag you just added:

```xml
        <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
          android:resource="@android:color/black" />
```

That will change the icon to black, but you can set your own colors in `res/values` as stated here: [Android System Color Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680262/android-system-color-constants)

Information about the meta-data tags is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: I did all but create the icon file, I just used my "@mipmap/ic_launcher" icon but it still displays white icon... why is this happening? I will try creating a new icon file

Comment: ok I made a text constant image and it works, I can change the color of the text but I have no idea how to change the background color or image

Comment: ok now I understand why it's white, it's because my icon image was circular, it needs to show some kind of transparency on the image. Solution works.

Comment: It should have been pretty obvious here but once made and fixed the mistake, it's important to put the <meta-data ... right under the android:icon... i.e.: NOT in <activity

Answer (score 0):

Once you done the steps mentioned above sometimes does not work and show default flutter icon.In this case, need to change or set Notification setting of [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) like this:

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body,
      payload: payload,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '@mipmap/your_icon_name',
        ),
          )
    );
```

for more information read this instruction

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, after all the research, I was able to change the service icon. Pay attention, the name of your photo must be ic_bg_service_small. According to the attached photo, you must create the drawable folders and add your own xml or png photos and use them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txWVv.png)

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    var androidInitialize =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings("ic_bg_service_small");
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

void initialNotify(
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    notificationId,
    'COOL SERVICE',
    '',
    const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        notificationChannelId,
        'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
        icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
        ongoing: true,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```