# Flutter - cannot see the notification icon on build APK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using flutter_local_notifications 4.0.1+2 with my project and the notification icon is visible when running debug apk in emulator but the build apk it shows an colored square instead of the icon. can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you didn't specify the notification icon at the correct place. It should be in the `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder, e.g. `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon.xml`. Then, you can add

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. It might be that you specified your icon in `android/app/src/debug/`, which does not get taken into account when building your release apk.

#### Edit

An example of `notification_icon.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="221.9dp"
    android:height="208.1dp"
    android:viewportWidth="221.9"
    android:viewportHeight="208.1">
  <path
      android:pathData="M152.4,0h-83L0,208.1h221.9L152.4,0zM110.9,56.4l18.6,57.7l60.6,-0.1l-49.1,35.5l18.8,57.6l-49,-35.7l-49,35.7l18.8,-57.6L31.7,114l60.6,0.1L110.9,56.4z"
      android:fillColor="#006600"
      android:fillType="evenOdd" />
</vector>
```

Comment: this is working but the color is white so i cant see the icon, then i used icon color meta tag inside manifest file but the icon is still white. But the debug apk colors works fine

Comment: You can specify the icon color with the fillColor property in the notification_icon.xml file. I added an example that would create a green icon. Again, make sure to make the edits in the main folder, not the debug one.

Comment: im using a image file. <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:value="#f77e0b" /> these are my meta tags but icon color stays white

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what's going wrong then; maybe you can convert your image to a vectorized path and use the fillColor tag like in my example, which should work just fine if your image isn't too detailed.

Comment: i did it as well with that also i can see the icon but its white. in white background i cant see the icon. i used a default clip art in this generator [Roman's Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html).

Comment: i found the issue. i fixed it by generating the icons using android asset studio. and directed the icon meta tag to @mipmap/ic_launcher.

Answer (score -1):

For showing your custom app icon, you need to set icon in  tag in Android Manifest file. Refer the following link, hope it may help you.

[Change notification black box with custom app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676014/how-to-change-the-android-notification-icon-status-bar-icon-for-push-notificatio)

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/nonstopio/change-the-firebase-notification-icon-in-a-flutter-245b7f7dc546)