# Small notification icon not showing in AndroidUsing flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-notification

I'm using push notifications in Flutter using one signal package. Notification is working fine but in some devices, the notification small icon is not showing it shows a blank square. in some devices, it shows correctly. anyone know how to solve this mostly face Android devices but not every device

I need to show the app launcher icon in the notification small icon part

Comment: check if your notification icon is in the right format. You can try, to generate the icon using this link: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html

Comment: already done with the same dimension shown in the docs 
also, try the sample icons provided on this website also 
but not showing

Comment: check this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/q/46676014/11287483

Comment: Adjust Icon Color. Some Android devices might have issues with the color of the small icon. You can try making the small icon entirely white (#FFFFFF) to ensure it appears correctly on all devices.