# How can a customised icon be set for Android Push Notifications?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, push-notification

Having recent success with sending and receiving my very first Firebase Cloud Message to an Android Emulator, I noticed that there was no logo on the notification.  The cloud message's title and body appeared on the notification but not a logo.

My first step to add an icon to the notifications was to reference a logo image within my the payload.  Doing this made no difference.

So at this stage my question is, how is the Android side of Flutter communicated with in order for the Android notifications to receive a customised icon and not the default Flutter icon?

Comment: You can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676014/how-to-change-the-android-notification-icon-status-bar-icon-for-push-notificatio)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Zee  As I am going through this right now, I intend to read, make notes and then add the highlights to this answer.  Also, I have come across some older answers that no longer work in 2024, so, the current documentation seems the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using flutter local notifications package then you can add a resource to the android settings while initialising the notification service.

In android/app/src/main/res/mipmap you can add a custom png different from you app icon and mention that in the Android Settings.

```dart
 const androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'App Name',
      'Channel_Id',
      channelAction: AndroidNotificationChannelAction.createIfNotExists,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      largeIcon:
      DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@mipmap/custom_png'),
    );
```

Something like this can be done and the package will communicate with android to get the image.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Yashas. I will look into your directions soon.  I have been trying to avoid a reliance on the Flutter Local Notifications package and work with the basics of Flutter instead.  Having tried a number things now and they not working also, I am encouraged to retry with FLN.

Comment: I don't know if you have noticed Android Developer's text on [create a notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification) but it interests me in AndroidX which makes a difference which by default is not offered to Flutter developers.  It could be that AndroidX opens the way for notification icons, and this idea led me to [adding AndroidX / AppCompat to Flutter](https://caiolandau.com/using-androidx-flutter-project) which I intend to try since AndroidX is available to Flutter developers too.

Comment: The chief difference is that I'd like my cloud messages to be sent from the application's server.  So, say I write a payload for Firebase Cloud Messaging,  I'd like to include details of the notification's icon within that payload.  FLN wants to send messages directly from Flutter instead - maybe as a way around configuring Flutter properly.

Comment: Playing around with the AndroidNotificationDetails object (as you suggested) led to the icon showing up within the android notifications.   This is exactly what I was looking for, and I suppose this means that I should now mark this chapter as done!  However, I will return to this because I believe that by composing code around the RemoteMessage object could eliminate the need of employing the Flutter Notifications Package - a package which worries me.  Many thanks for your response : )  Also, I have gathered that FCM covers background messages only,  and FLN covers the foreground aspect.