# Why do we put integer values in Constant class in Java/Android?

Tags: constants

As integer values are primitive, so we can't use it as a reference. But In Android project, would anybody please tell what is the reason behind to put this type of value in another constant class.

Comment: Don't, it's bad practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866603/9204.

Comment: Thanks,Alexey Romanov.